# Posting multiple JSON objects in flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I am fairly new to the world of web development and I am tryin to figure out if it is possible to make two posts out of one request.json object using curl X POST. For example, if I type

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"income":500, "age" : 4, "gender" : "male"}' http://localhost:5000/house
```

into the command line. I get

```
[
  {
    "income": 500.0, 
    "members": [
      {
        "age": 22, 
        "gender": "male"
      }
    ], 
    "unique_id": 0
  }, 
  {
    "income": 500.0, 
    "members": [
      {
        "age": 4, 
        "gender": "male"
      }
    ], 
    "unique_id": 1
  }
]
```

as the output. What I am trying to do is to get another member(age and gender JSON object), I have tried using curl X POST like this

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"income":500, "age" : 4, "gender" : "female", "age" : 22, "gender" : "male"}' http://localhost:5000/house
```

and the output should look like

```
[
  {
    "income": 500.0, 
    "members": [
      {
        "age": 22, 
        "gender": "male"
      }
    ], 
    "unique_id": 0
  }, 
  {
    "income": 500.0, 
    "members": [
      {
        "age": 4, 
        "gender": "female"
        "age" : 22
        "gender" : "male"
      }
    ], 
    "unique_id": 1
  }
]
```

But instead I am getting

```
[
  {
    "income": 500.0, 
    "members": [
      {
        "age": 22, 
        "gender": "male"
      }
    ], 
    "unique_id": 0
  }, 
  {
    "income": 500.0, 
    "members": [
      {
        "age": 22, 
        "gender": "male"
      }
    ], 
    "unique_id": 1
  }
]
```

As you can see, it is only posting the last JSON age and gender object that I type. Is there any way to remedy this so it posts both age and gender JSON objects. My code is below. Thanks.

```
households = []   

@app.route('/house', methods=['POST'])   
def post_household():

    """this here gives us our unique id by counting the number of household objects
    we have in our households list"""
    unique_id = len(households)

    house = Household({
        'unique_id' : unique_id,   
        'income': request.json['income'],
        'members':[
            {
            'age': request.json['age'],
            'gender': request.json['gender']
            },
        ]})
    """turns the Household object back into a dictionary so it can be jsonified"""
    return_to_dictionary = house.to_primitive()
    """append our newly created dictionary to our households list"""
    households.append(return_to_dictionary)
    return jsonify(households)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this json

```
"members": [
      {
        "age": 4, 
        "gender": "female"
        "age" : 22
        "gender" : "male"
      }
    ]
```

You have two sets of the same keys ("age" and "gender"), so json serializer would take the last value present for each duplicate key.(See this link: [Duplicate Keys in JSON objects](https://dzone.com/articles/duplicate-keys-in-json-objects)). Maybe you can use this format instead,which also groups age and gender attributes together (eg: the female is 4 years old)

```
"members": [
          {
            "age": 4, 
            "gender": "female"
           },
           {
            "age" : 22
            "gender" : "male"
          }
        ]
```

Comment: I tried posting it that way but it gave me a key error

Comment: -X POST -d '{"income":500, "members" : [{ "age" : 4, "gender" : "female"}, {"age" : 22, "gender" : "male"}]}' http://localhost:5000/house

Comment: Can you try   "di = request.json" "di['unique_id'] = unique_id"  "house = Household(di)"